# Imported linked libraries resets back when rebuilt - how to avoid for specific libraries?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json, yarnpkg

I'm trying to make modifications to some of the imported libraries that I added using `yarn`. When I make a change to those libraries under `node_modules`, and then run `react-native run-android`, modifications are updated then. But when I run `react-native run-android` the next time, it gets reset back to the original.

I wanna make changes to it and save it with my custom modifications. How do I avoid it getting reset back to the original library? This question might sound really basic and stupid, but I have no idea how to and I can't find any solution to this when I tried to search a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

`node_modules` must not be changed manually as it is assumed to be read-only dependency.

If you still want to change one of node_modules , you have three ways :

1. Create a pull-request which contains your changes to the repository of this module and follow up with the  owner of repository until merge the pull-request and **publish** your changes in `npmjs.com`.

   Definitely, this solution  can take much time which breaks your productivity . If so , the best solution is :
2. Fork the repository of the module , make changes  and if the license allows you , publish your repo under `https://npmjs.com` using

   ```
   cd /path/to/your-repo-after-changes;
   npm publish;
   ```

Then go back to your project and run :

```
 yarn add your-repo-after-changes ;
```

3. According to license, you may copy/paste the module source code that you want to change to your project under a folder (`external-modules` for example) , make your changes and export from external-modules .